# Please help identify the LEGO set

Tags: set-identification

Got the picture of the main fuselage with 3 troopers.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [ARC-170 Starfighter (7259)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7259-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, found it as set #7259

Comment: @nnLego My bad, 7529 was a typo. URL indeed points to 7259.